# Integration within boundaries with irrational powers

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate
$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[a]{1-x^{a}}\ dx$$ 
where $a^{1-\sqrt{0.5}}=0.5$.

I can calculate this when $a=2$, but what if $a$ is something else  or it is irrational like here?

Comment: Hint: Substitute $x^a=u$ and you'll get a [Euler integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_integral)

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: What do you get after the substitution I suggested?

Comment: Can't say,I don't know about it

Comment: You don't know how to apply a $u$-substitution?

Comment: No i don't Is there an easier way?

Comment: No. Do you know about chain rule? Its basically that but for integrals.

Comment: Oo,is there a link for it on wikipedia?

Comment: Do you know the fundamental theorem of calculus for integrals?

Answer (score 2):

Note that we have any $a>0$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (1-x^a)^{1/a}\,dx&\overbrace{=}^{x\to x^{1/a}}\frac1a\int_0^1 (1-x)^{1/a}x^{1/a-1}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1a B(1/a,1/a+1)\\\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(1/a)\,\Gamma(1/a+1)}{a\Gamma(2/a+1)}\\\\
&=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/a)}{2a\Gamma(2/a)}\tag 1
\end{align}$$

For $a=2$, we see that

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{1/2}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma^2(1/2)}{4\Gamma(1)}=\frac\pi4$$

as expected.

---

For $a^{1-\sqrt{1/2}}=1/2$, we have

$$\int_0^1 (1-x^a)^{1/a}\,dx\approx 2.23485 \times 10^{-6} $$

Comment: So for the given a what'll be the value?

Comment: @ShauryamAkhoury A mess that can be reduced to an algebraic multiple of $\Gamma^2(1/a)/\Gamma(2/a)$

Comment: Sooo what's  the answer?

Comment: For $a^{1-\sqrt{0.5}}=0.5$, $a\approx 0.093803557$.  Then, the integral of interest is approximately $2.23485 \times 10^{-6}$.

Comment: Shouldn't a = 0.5644763?

Comment: $$a=e^{\log(0.5)/( 1-\sqrt{0.5})}$$